# How to determine the fewest number of each different coin needed to represent that entered amount?

Tags: java

I am very new to programing, and I am having trouble with this program which wants the user to enter a number of "alien coins" called novas and then determines the fewest number of each different alien coin needed to represent that amount, starting with the highest. Here are the coins and what they are worth:

- 1 aurora = 60 pulsars
- 1 pulsar = 70 gravitons
- 1 graviton = 6 novas

Here is a sample input and output on how it should look:

```
Enter number of novas: 64197 [Enter]
That number of novas is equal to: 
2 auroras 
32 pulsars 
59 gravitons 
3 novas
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class AlienMoney {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int startAmount, amount, auroras, pulsars, gravitons, novas; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of novas: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("That number of novas is equal to: ");

        startAmount = amount;
        gravitons = amount / 6;
        amount = amount % 6;
        pulsars = amount / 70;
        amount = amount % 70;
        auroras = amount / 60;
        amount = amount % 60;
        novas = amount;

        System.out.println(auroras + " auroras");
        System.out.println(pulsars + " pulsars");
        System.out.println(gravitons + " gravitons");
        System.out.println(novas + " novas");


    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Enter number of novas: 64197 [Enter]
That number of novas is equal to: 
0 auroras 
0 pulsars 
10699 gravitons 
3 novas
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I know I definitely have to use the modulus operator `%` to get the remainder, but I am not sure what to do after that. I would greatly appreciate anyone's help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate your currencies in the correct order, starting from the largest.

So:
aurora > pulsar > graviton > nova

Instead of:
graviton > pulsar > aurora > nova

Comment: This explanation is correct.  Include code next time for better results.

Answer (score 0):

The approach in the code snippet below is to compute the number of novas in each of the three coins, and then to calculate how many of each coin to use to represent the amount entered.

In order to use the fewest number of coins, we should begin by using as many auroras as possible, with the remainder as pulsars, followed by gravitons last.

```
int auroras = amount / (6 * 70 * 60);
int remainder = amount % (6 * 70 * 60);
int pulsars = remainder / (6 * 70);
remainder = remainder %  (6 * 70);
int graviton = remainder / 6;
int novas = remainder % 6;
```

Answer (score -1):

Right here, problem lines indicated in comments:

```
startAmount = amount;
gravitons = amount / 6;
amount = amount % 6;
pulsars = amount / 70; // <-- starts here
amount = amount % 70;
auroras = amount / 60;
amount = amount % 60;
novas = amount;
```

You're using the wrong variables. Use the variables you assigned the needed amount into instead, e.g.:

```
startAmount = amount;
gravitons = amount / 6;
amount %= 6;
pulsars = gravitons / 70;
gravitons %= 70;
auroras = pulsars / 60;
pulsars %= 60;
novas = amount; // this doesn't need to change but there's no need to assign amount into a new variable
```

Also use the `%=` operator. It's pretty cool. ;)

Comment: This isn't correct because it assigns the smaller denomination coins _first_, which will result in the _greatest_ number of nova coins being used.

Comment: It *does* assign them first, but it also converts them into the higher denominations later, so it still works.